# How to detect if an iOS device has downloaded a voice file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-to-speech

I'm working on an iOS text to speech app and trying to add an option to use the Alex voice, which is new for iOS 9. I need to determine whether or not the user has downloaded the Alex voice in Settings -> Accessibility. I can't seem to find out how to do this.

```
if ([AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithIdentifier:AVSpeechSynthesisVoiceIdentifierAlex] == "Not Found" ) {
    // Do something...
}
```

The reason is the other language voices that are standard, play back at a certain rate, different from the Alex voice. So I have a working app, but if the user hasn't downloaded the voice, iOS automatically defaults to a basic voice, but it plays back at the incorrect rate. If I can detect the voice hasn't been downloaded, I can compensate for the difference and / or advise the user.

Comment: An interesting and nicely formatted question +1

Answer (score 3):

OK, so I guess I was overthinking this and thought it was more complicated. The solution was simple.

```
if (![AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithIdentifier:AVSpeechSynthesisVoiceIdentifierAlex]) {
        // Normalize the speech rate since the user hasn't downloaded the voice and/or trigger a notification that they need to go into settings and download the voice. 
    }
```

Thanks to everyone who looked at this and to @CeceXX for the edit. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `[AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithIdentifier:]` method seems to be missing from iOS 9.1+. To be replaced with the much less useful 'voiceWithLanguage'.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. Let's stick with Alex as an example:

```
- (void)checkForAlex {

        // is Alex installed?
        BOOL alexInstalled = NO;
        NSArray *voices = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice speechVoices];

        for (id voiceName in voices) {

            if ([[voiceName valueForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:@"Alex"]) {
                alexInstalled = YES;
            }
        }

        // react accordingly
        if (alexInstalled) {
            NSLog(@"Alex is installed on this device.");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Alex is not installed on this device.");
        }
    }
```

This method loops through all installed voices and queries each voice's name. If Alex is among them, he's installed.

Other values you can query are "language" (returns a language code like en-US) and quality (1 = standard, 2 = enhanced).